# GameKit Issue : PeerPicker identifies the devices only when the other devices have picker visible

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit, gkpeerpickercontroller

I an working with the gameKit framework.  I wanted to show the list of devices available near by. So I am using peerPicker controller to identify the devices running the app. I am able to identify and add the devices to my tableView. I am facing some issues

1) It displays the devices which also have a peerPicker controller searching. I mean If I simply launch my app and does not present the peerPickerController then my device does not get listed in the peerPickerController's device list on another app.

2) It is behaving very slowly. After I accept the connection request , it almost takes 20 seconds to respond.

3) Can't I have the bluetooth session in multiple devices at the same time ??

Please help me !!!

Thank You !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to show the device in a list without presenting the peer peer then there is no need to use GKPeerPickerController.
Just use GKSession class and use its delegates for peer lists.
you just need to set GKSession class available property to YES, it will be detected by other GKSession automatically.

2) Its bug, we cant do anything related to that.

3) Can you please explain how you want to use that?

Comment: Sometime its showing same device name multiple time ..isnt it?

Comment: Thats right.But using UINavigationController to our view controller will solve this problem.